# Conditional probability proof

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

could anyone help with this problem below:

Show that if $P(A|E) \geq P(B|E)$ and $P(A|E^c) \geq P(B|E^c)$, then $P(A) \geq P(B)$.

I have been trying to apply Bayes' Rule and the law of total probability to this question but have not been able to solve it successfully. Thanks!

Comment: See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308442/if-pa-mid-e-pb-mid-e-and-pa-mid-neg-e-pb-mid-neg-e-then-i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $P(A \mid E) \gt P(B \mid E)$ and $P(A \mid \neg E) \gt P(B \mid \neg E)$, then is $P(A) \gt P(B)$ true?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308442/if-pa-mid-e-pb-mid-e-and-pa-mid-neg-e-pb-mid-neg-e-then-i)